# Can one send a zero value transaction from any address to any address?

Tags: transaction, security, address, signing

Since zero value transactions do not require a signature, I assume one can send 0 value tx **from any address**, even if he does not own the corresponding seed.

Is this assumption correct?

Comment: is it free to send this type of transaction from address to any address?

Comment: Yes, since you do not have to sign a 0 value tx, you can send it from and to any address.

Comment: @user3785971 All transactions are free (of transaction fees), including 0 value transactions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically speaking, a zero value transaction (bundle) neither needs to have nor can have a sender address. (Sending transactions in a bundle have `value < 0` and receiving transactions have `value ≥ 0`).

That being said, you can send zero value transactions **to** any address. No funds will be moved and the address will not get added to the next snapshot either (unless there were some non-zero transactions as well).

The address does not need to be valid either (it only needs to be a valid Kerl hash, but the hash does not have to be from a valid private key), which is utilized by MAM and by the reclaim process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is indeed the case. When you use a spammer to create transactions, they will always have a random address.

MAM uses addresses as a message ID for example, as these data transfers are also zero-value. You can take a look at their blog for more information https://blog.iota.org/introducing-masked-authenticated-messaging-e55c1822d50e