# How to sign a data transaction?

Tags: masked-authenticated-messaging, bundles, signing, data

I am wondering if it is possible to sign a data transaction, i.e. generate a signed bundle whose inputs have a balance of 0. If so, how could I construct such a bundle?

I am asking because I would like to know how a zero value transaction can be known to have been sent from someone with access to a specific address.

Thanks

Comment: https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1266/can-one-send-a-zero-value-transaction-from-any-address-to-any-address