# Adress reuse with zero value transactions

Tags: transaction, security, address, address-reuse, signing

If I send multiple zero value transactions from address `A`, containing several messages to broker a deal, is it safe to (re)use that address later on for a payment (to settle the deal)?

Comment: In my opinion it should be, since the the zero value transaction don't get signed.

Comment: zero value transactions [do not have a **from**](https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/1275/134)

Comment: @mihi They don't need a from. But at least in devnet it's posible to set a from address. The application I'm developing kind of relies on the fact that the entity messaging is also the one paying later on.

Comment: it depends on what libs you are using. When you are using devnet, can you post a transaction hash or link to devnet.thetangle.org? I'm curious where your library is hiding the "from" address and "to" address in a transaction that only has one address field :)

Comment: Oh, there is only one address!? Maybe I'm misusing the to address as from address. Here's a [transaction](https://devnet.thetangle.org/transaction/VESVAAG9OYYDATUJ9CXDGZ9OKSNEJFBLCBGFMPOTBJZKFSFKNEHLYNXIEINIRDSAMPLZSMZMHZ9E99999).

Comment: The corresponding [bundle](https://devnet.thetangle.org/bundle/AI9TLLHXNXJFAVUWGB9XAPNIJVTHHZNIBHNBNLUWBLJQUPNZYCHGVEGERLTAQT9AHLTEYDHXKVQFLHDIX) shows it as an output address :)

Comment: Okay, I've been using it wrong then. But I have no need for a to address, since I use tags for message relaying. So I guess, I can leave it like that :D Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero value transactions don't need to be signed but you can sign them, either by mistake or by using a buggy library and in this case: it is unsafe to re-use the same address.

I can't find the reference right now, but I think that a bug like that was once reported with js library. (it was probably with the old js library)